# How to change request function order in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, ghost-blog

I'm trying to use a Ghost app as a sub-app to my main Express application, running on the "/blog" path.

The way the Ghost documentation recommends it, I should have this

```
ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
  app.use("/blog", ghostServer.rootApp);
  ghostServer.start(app);
});
```

However, I took Express's preferred spin on things, where the end of my app.js includes error handling in the case of 404 (the path can be found neither as a view nor as a file in the public folder, which is true in the case of "/blog"). What this means is that `app.use("/blog", ghostServer.rootApp);` comes **after** error checking, so, while I can access my Ghost server if I comment out my error handling (which, obviously, I don't really want to do), I can't access it otherwise.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Would be nice if you included the actual code. But maybe try moving the `app.use` code before the error handling.

Comment: The code snippet I put up there *is* before the error handling, but `ghost()` returns a Promise, so the `app.use` is actually being called after the whole script runs (because it's in a block that's called asynchronously)

Comment: It might be that the error handling is getting registered before the promise is fulfilled. Maybe move the error handling inside of the promise so it gets registered after the `/blog` handler.

Comment: I suppose that would work, but that seems even messier than the solution I've proposed. Additionally, if (theoretically) the ghost server encounters an issue and does not start, my site would have to go without error handling because the promise would never be fulfilled.

Comment: Possibly just implement it in a `finally` handler instead, then it would always run. `ghost().then(function() {...}).finally(function() { // register 400 handlers})`. I agree though, not very pretty :(

Comment: Yeah, that solves the error handling issue, but I kind of prefer my solution right now, if only because it means I can keep ghost at the top of the file and the error handlers at the bottom and outside of an unrelated scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I should be putting this as an answer, but I have a solution which I don't think is the best way to do it, but it does seem to work.

```
var gs = null;
ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
  gs = ghostServer;
  ghostServer.start(app);
});

app.use('/blog', function (req, res, next) {
  if (gs) gs.rootApp(req, res, next);
  else next();
});
```

This way, the app.use is actually being called synchronously. However, this is definitely not the most efficient way to do this (as it adds one function call to the stack every time a request is made to "/blog")

I'd love to see a better answer than this.